# Disabling or Enabling Radio Buttons According To Groups

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I have created two groups of radio buttons. I want to set the radio buttons to the enable and disable function where users are only allowed to select one of the `Yes` radio buttons in the both groups.

For instance, users can either choose `Yes1` or `Yes2` button at once. When user clicks on the `Yes1` button, the `Yes2` buttons's selection should be disabled and automatically selects the `No2` button.

I have tried most of the codes posted by various developers in this website but nothing seem to help. Plus, I am not used to jQuery language, I prefer Javascript.

I need some guidance in this.

Note : I need to do it ONLY for Radio Buttons.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <label id="group2">
    <td>Drop</td>
    <td>
 <input type="text" value="0" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/>
 </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes" checked="checked">Yes1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No">No1</td>
  </label>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <label id="group3">
    <td>Power</td>
    <td>
 <input type="text" value="0" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes">Yes2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"  checked="checked">No2</td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better represented as two checkboxes rather than two groups of yes/no radios? Then you could code it so checking either checkbox automatically unchecks the other, still allowing neither to be checked. (That way the user doesn't have to first change the answer in one section before changing their answer in the other.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the feedback. I have many groups of radio buttons in a page and my professor wants me to do it only in Radio Buttons. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plain JS solution, using a delegated event handling model where I've bound a single click handler to the table containing all of the radio buttons, then within that handler I test whether the clicked item was a radio and if so process accordingly.

In a comment above you said you have lots of Yes/No groups: the code I've written can handle any number of Yes/No groups; for demonstration purposes I've added a third group.

*Edit: you asked in a comment to only do this for radio buttons with a certain class. Answer updated to do that by adding a `"limited"` class (obviously the class name could be anything) and testing for that as appropriate. (Check the edit history to see how to do it for all radios without using classes.)*

```js
// Should give the container an ID, but for now select by table tag:
var container = document.querySelector('table')
// Get a list of all "Yes" radios:
var yesRadios = container.querySelectorAll('input[value="Yes"].limited')

// Add a click handler to the containing table element:
container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("limited")) return  // Ignore clicks on non-radio elements
  
  // Set each "Yes" radio's disabled state according to whether it was
  // the clicked item and whether the clicked item was a "Yes":
  yesRadios.forEach(function(rad, i) {
    rad.disabled = rad != e.target && e.target.value === "Yes"
  })
})
```

```html
<p>Note: disabling only applies to last two rows.</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <label id="group2">
    <td>Drop</td>
    <td>
 <input type="text" value="0" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/>
 </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes">Yes1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No" checked="checked">No1</td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <label id="group3">
    <td>Power</td>
    <td>
 <input type="text" value="0" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes" class="limited">Yes2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No" class="limited" checked="checked">No2</td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <label id="group3">
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>
 <input type="text" value="0" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="6" size="4" readonly="readonly"/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes" class="limited">Yes3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No" class="limited" checked="checked">No3</td>
  </label>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that your current HTML is invalid, because you shouldn't have label elements as immediate children of the tr elements, but I've left that as is.

Further reading:

- [`.addEventListner()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
- [Event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Your codes are well explained and understandable but is it possible to replace the `[value="Yes"]` with any class name instead? As what I have is many groups of Yes and No radio buttons but I just want to apply the event listener to only certain radio buttons.

Comment: Answer updated to use classes on each Yes and No that you want to apply this processing to.

Comment: I am not sure why, the codes don't seem to work on mine :(

Comment: Note that the JS would need to be in a script element *after* the elements in question. I recommend putting it just before the closing `</body>` tag. Beyond that, you can see my demo snippet works so I'm not sure what else to tell you other than to check your browser's console for errors and deal with them as needed.

Comment: I've followed and done as advised. But I'm not sure why isn't it working. Will multiple tables in the codes effect the script?

Comment: Yes. The first line of my code applies this to the *first* table in the document, which is why I put a comment in the code about giving the table an ID. The `container` selected on that line needs to be whatever element contains *all* of the radios you want to handle, so if they don't have a common container just use `document.body` instead.

Comment: It works perfectly now ! I just changed the `document.querySelector('table')` to `document.body` and it worked ! Thanks a bunch man.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super clear on your objective based on your question, but here is some example code which may show you how to approach your problem (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // set to no by default
  $("input[name=group2]").val(["No"]);
  // set to Yes and enabled by default
  $("input[name=group3]").val(["Yes"]);
  $("input[name=group3]").prop("disabled", false);

  $("input[name=group2]").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
      $("input[name=group3]").val(["No"]);
      $("input[name=group3]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
      $("input[name=group3]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/LOrRxB)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I would choose JavaScript over jQuery. But I really do appreciate your work. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote in the comments section that you will have multiple groups to enable/disable here are some general guidelines of what needs to be done:

1. Give all the radio buttons that effect other buttons a class (for example, `group-that-disable`) and add a data attribute that connects each radio button to the radio buttons it should disable. For example:

`<td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes" checked="checked" class="group-that-disable" data-group="3">Yes1</td>`

`<td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No" class="group-that-disable" data-group="3">No1</td>`

2. Add an event listener for that class that will trigger when the status of a radio button changes.
3. Lastly, use the data attribute of the changed radio button to determine and locate the radio buttons that require enabling/disabling and adjust them as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Your explanation helped me much.